# R- Unpivot double columns

Tags: r, unpivot

I have a dataset like this (yes, with double titles, as these are mandatory from my BI tool):

```
library(readxl)
df = read_excel("df.xlsx")
View(df)
Firm November November December December etc etc
Firm On-time  Pieces   On-time  Pieces   etc etc
A    37%      60       50%      10
B    60%      50       10%      55
```

Which I would much prefer in following format:

```
Firm Month    On-time Pieces
A    December 50%     10
A    November 37%     60
Etc
etc
```

I tried:

```
df %>%
gather(month, ot, -firm) %>%
filter(firm != "firm") %>%
arrange(firm)
```

But it did not give me what I wanted. Above function gave me on-time and pieces in one column, mixed up.

I couldn't find this anywhere, but if you find it, please comment and I will of course delete the post.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::gather()`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGustar, but I can't seem to get the columns seperated

Comment: So have you actually read this into a data frame or some other object type? What happens if you do `names(df)`?  Is everything a factor because the first row has the second names?

Comment: @Elin good question. The original file was a .xlsx, which I loaded using the readxl package and read_excel(). I'm not sure how you want me to respond, however, the data shows nicely as a file with 352 obs. of 21 variables. Does this answer your question?

Comment: When you say "show" what do you mean?  Can you please put the results of your names() function in your question?   R column names normally cannot have two lines ... are those linebreaks or are they really long names?

Comment: @Elin shows in the global environment of R Studio.

Comment: What does? Is your data frame named `df`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can reduce your double row of headings to a single row so that you have a dataframe of the following form...

```
df
  Firm Nov-OnTime Nov-Pieces Dec-OnTime Dec-Pieces
1    A        37%         60        50%         10
2    B        60%         50        10%         55
```

then you can use a `gather - separate - spread` sequence to produce what you want...

```
library (tidyr)
df2 <- df %>% gather(key=key, value=value, -Firm) %>%       #gather all columns except Firm
    separate(key, into=c("Month", "Type"), remove=TRUE) %>% #split into month and type
    spread(key=Type, value=value)                           #spread by Type (keeping month)

df2
  Firm Month OnTime Pieces
1    A   Dec    50%     10
2    A   Nov    37%     60
3    B   Dec    10%     55
4    B   Nov    60%     50
```

Comment: Thanks - this works, however, I would much prefer not to, as I have many columns. :-D

Comment: @ChristianR.Houen Prefer not to what? If it is the column names, you could do something like `names(df) <- paste0(names(df),df[1,],sep="-")` (and perhaps `names(df)[1] <- "Firm"`), and then delete the first row `df <- df[-1,]`.